# excel with vba formula if then print

Tags: vba

I am trying to get this macro to work with excel. It will look at the value of three cells, if any cell is less than 60 it will print it. If not, it will move onto the next name on the data validation and continue. It keeps on printing the entire range.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+L
'
Dim r As Long, i As Long

r = Range("SOLDIERS").Cells.Count

For i = 1 To r
    Range("B12") = Range("SOLDIERS").Cells(i)

If e32 < 60 Or g32 < 60 Or h32 < 60 Then
ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=1

Else: End If


Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify `Option Explicit` at the top, and then the VBE will refuse to compile your code and complain about `e32`, `g32` and `h32` being undeclared variables - if these mean to be range addresses on the active sheet, then they should be `Range("E32").Value`, `Range("G32").Value` and `Range("H32").Value`, respectively.

Note that if either cell contains a cell error value (e.g. `#VALUE!`), then the comparisons will blow up with a *type mismatch* error. You can avoid this with e.g. `If IsNumeric(Range("E32").Value) Then`, so that the comparison is only executed when you're dealing with a numeric value (error values can't be compared to anything). You can also test specifically whether a cell contains an error value with the `IsError` function.

Comment: the range B12 is my data validation drop down. The E32,G32, and h32 are auto populated from other pages in the work book.

Comment: @donaldpanaway and the `If e32 < 60 Or g32 < 60 Or h32 < 60 Then` expression is referring to undeclared local variables, not `Range` objects. `e32` isn't how you refer to cell E32 in VBA. You got the B12 range correctly - use similar syntax to access all the cells you need to access.

Comment: appreciate it I'm very green when it comes to this and trying to get my way through the weeds.